# pip install django-import-export raises SyntaxError

Tags: python, django, pip, django-import-export

There are what seem to be dozens of questions about "why does pip raise SyntaxError?" and all the answers are "run it from the system shell, not the python shell."  This isn't one of those questions.  I installed django-import-export using pip, and got a number of SyntaxErrors in the output.  The module itself seems to work fine, just wondering what's up with the SystaxErrors.

Here's the entire output:

```
c:\Dev\Website>pip install django-import-export
Downloading/unpacking django-import-export
  Running setup.py (path:c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_username\django-import-export\setup.py) egg_info for pac
kage django-import-export

Downloading/unpacking tablib (from django-import-export)
Downloading/unpacking diff-match-patch (from django-import-export)
  Running setup.py (path:c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_username\diff-match-patch\setup.py) egg_info for package
 diff-match-patch

Installing collected packages: django-import-export, tablib, diff-match-patch
  Running setup.py install for django-import-export

Compiling c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_username\tablib\tablib\packages\xlrd3\__init__.py ...
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_username\tablib\tablib\packages\xlrd3\__init__.py", line 855
    print("mem: %s, base: %d, len: %d" % (type(self.mem), self.base, self.stream_len), file=self.logfile)
                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Compiling c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_username\tablib\tablib\packages\xlrd3\biffh.py ...
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_username\tablib\tablib\packages\xlrd3\biffh.py", line 386
    print(header, file=f)
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Compiling c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_username\tablib\tablib\packages\xlrd3\compdoc.py ...
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_username\tablib\tablib\packages\xlrd3\compdoc.py", line 89
    print("\nCompDoc format: version=0x%04x revision=0x%04x" % (version, revision), file=logfile)
                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Compiling c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_username\tablib\tablib\packages\xlrd3\formatting.py ...
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_username\tablib\tablib\packages\xlrd3\formatting.py", line 589
    print("%2d: %r -> %r" % (i, old_rgb, new_rgb), file=book.logfile)
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Compiling c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_username\tablib\tablib\packages\xlrd3\formula.py ...
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_username\tablib\tablib\packages\xlrd3\formula.py", line 794
    if verbose: print("tIsect pre", stack, file=bk.logfile)
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Compiling c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_username\tablib\tablib\packages\xlrd3\sheet.py ...
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_username\tablib\tablib\packages\xlrd3\sheet.py", line 466
    print("put_cell", rowx, colx, file=self.logfile)
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Compiling c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_username\tablib\tablib\packages\xlwt3\antlr.py ...
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_username\tablib\tablib\packages\xlwt3\antlr.py", line 1946
    print(fmt % (line,col,text), file=sys.stderr)
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  Running setup.py install for diff-match-patch

Successfully installed django-import-export tablib diff-match-patch
Cleaning up...

c:\Dev\Website>python -c "import import_export; print(import_export)"
<module 'import_export' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\import_export\__init__.pyc'>
```

Comment: That looks like Python 3, where `print` is a function instead of a keyword

Comment: print(... is python 3 syntax and looks like you are using python 2.7.

pip install django-import-export==0.1.6  you may want to unistall the current version first

Comment: https://github.com/bmihelac/django-import-export/blob/master/README.rst indicates that the  requirements are "Python 2.7+ or Python 3.3+".  I'll drop a message to the contributors.  Thanks!

Comment: I just looked at the errors a little more... its not django-import-export.  Its tablib that is causing you problems.  You could try to pip install tablib==0.9.11  thats the version that django-import-export says it supports